# MongoID query for a collection that references a collection that references a collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I have a User model, a Workout model and a Exercise model. I am using Devise for user management and MongoID to interact with MongoDB.

User **references_many :workouts**
Workout **references_many :exercises** and **referenced_in :user**
Exercise **referenced_in: workout**

How do I query the database to give me a list of all the **current_user** exercises.I have not stored the user.id in the exercise collection, only the workout.id.

Is it possible, or should I rework the model to store the user_id in both the exercise and workout collections?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

workout_ids = Workout.where(:user_id => current_user.id ).all.collect { |w| w.id }

exercises = Exercise.where(:workout_id => { "$in" => workout_ids })

Comment: Thanks but I get an error stating that I cannot serialize an object of class user: http://d.pr/myTZ

Comment: I updated the example to pass "current_user.id" instead of "current_user".